# How to be informed when user changes the language keyboard layout in Windows?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I want to show a message to user when the user changes **the language keyboard layout of Windows** for example from **EN to FR**. But I don't know how can I be informed when the user changes it using either the taskbar or <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>. Which win32api function should I use?
I need something like this pseudocode :

```
void inputLanguageChanged(char *ln)
{
  message("You selected " + ln + " language");
}
```

Comment: In case the user don't know (s)he changed it? I usually do...

Comment: @MatsPetersson unfortunately the default key combinations tend to be extremely annoyingly easy to press by mistake

Comment: There are better solutions for that than writing a program that displays annoying alerts of the obvious: [Why does Windows change the input language randomly?](http://superuser.com/q/453) and [Why are my computer's language settings changing at undesirable times?](http://superuser.com/q/242112)

Comment: @CodyGray ~> No this is a sample. I need it for something else.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The traditional way of doing this was to handle the [`WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE` message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632629.aspx). But there are a couple of problems with this method:

- it is only sent to the active (focused) window, and
- [it doesn't catch all possible cases, and may not be reliable on modern versions of Windows](http://www.siao2.com/2006/05/16/598980.aspx).

The better solution, then, is to implement the [`ITfLanguageProfileNotifySink` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms628769.aspx), whose [`OnLanguageChanged` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms628772.aspx) is called whenever the input language changes, regardless of the way that it was changed.

However, I see that your question is tagged with both the C and C++ tags. You *can* use COM from C, but it's a real pain in the neck. Far simpler if you're using C++. If I needed to do this work in a C program, I'd probably just find a way to make `WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE` work for me. Maybe I'm just lazy.

Comment: Big thanks :) . My problem with WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE is that I don't know how to get the current keyboard layout string. I can get its id but how to convert it to a user-readable string.

Comment: @saeed Just call [`GetKeyboardLayoutName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646298.aspx). That returns the name of the keyboard layout for the calling thread.

Comment: I'm sorry but I used it before but it returns an string like **00000429** . My code is : `char * lang = new char[KL_NAMELENGTH ];` `GetKeyboardLayoutNameA(lang);`

Comment: @saeed Hmm yeah, that's because it returns whatever was passed to `LoadKeyboardLayout`. The only other way is reading the information from the registry. That really should be asked as a new question, but [this blog article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michkap/archive/2006/05/06/591174.aspx) might help.

Comment: @saeed You're welcome. Also, why are you calling ANSI functions? Windows apps should be all Unicode now. Use `wchar_t` and `GetKeyboardLayoutNameW`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE` message:

```cpp
case WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE:
{
    HKL hkl = (HKL)lParam;
    WCHAR localeName[LOCALE_NAME_MAX_LENGTH];
    LCIDToLocaleName(MAKELCID(LOWORD(hkl), SORT_DEFAULT), localeName, LOCALE_NAME_MAX_LENGTH, 0);

    WCHAR lang[9];
    GetLocaleInfoEx(localeName, LOCALE_SISO639LANGNAME2, lang, 9);
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/intl/locale-names
https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/intl/nls--name-based-apis-sample