# CM_INPUTLANGCHANGE message doesn't work in Delphi TComboBox

Tags: delphi

In Delphi(XE5 and Windows 10) and new application, There is a combobox and a textbox on the form.
I have implemented this procedure and when the focus is on the combobox and I press the combination keys SHIFT+ALT, Combobox does not receive this message :

`procedure OnChangeLanguageEvent(var Msg: TMessage); message CM_INPUTLANGCHANGE;`

Anyone got any idea what's going wrong please?

Comment: [According to this](https://www.delphipower.xyz/handbook_2010/input_language_and_language_libraries.html): "*the Windows wm_InputLangChange message now triggers an internal component message, cm_InputLangChange, which is broadcasted to all windowed controls. You can intercept and process this message in a TWinControl descendant*", which implies that your app is likely not receiving WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE to begin with. See [How to be informed when user changes the language keyboard layout in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907855/)

Comment: @RemyLebeau, You are right when focus on TComboBox (My app does not receive WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE message) but when focus on TEdit my application receive both WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE and CM_INPUTLANGCHANGE messages.

Comment: "*The better solution, then, is to implement the ITfLanguageProfileNotifySink interface, whose OnLanguageChanged method is called whenever the input language changes, regardless of the way that it was changed.*" This is also described by [What broke the input language messages?](http://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2006/05/16/598980.html): "*Those two USER messages [WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST and  WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE] can no longer be relied on at all... The replacement which will work for both regular keyboards and TSF Text Services is the ITfLanguageProfileNotifySink interface*"